# I asked "him" if he could swim - what is this sentence element called?

Tags: terminology

> I asked **him** if he could swim.

Downing, in her book 'English Grammar,' describes this kind of construction as:

> subject + verb + NG(a **Recipient**) + Wh-complement clause.

(In Downing's terminology NG = nominal group, eqivalent to ‘noun phrase’)

However, my other syntax books have examples that have no such NG.

So I want to know by what name syntax books call *him* in the example.

Comment: _Him_ is the direct object of _ask_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think not. In traditional grammar the **DO** is the clause (*if he could swim*); *him* is the **Indirect Object**. "I asked him [**IO**] a question [**DO**]." My guess is that OP's book characterizes *if he could swim* as a Wh-complement clause  **a)** on the basis of its alternate form *whether he could swim* and **b)** to maintain consistency with clauses like *what his name was* or *who he lived with* or *when he was coming*.

Comment: Whoops... Yes, it is an indirect object. I was hoping the reply could be "The OP is not asking about direct or indirect object." :)

Comment: "Ask" can be [monotransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotransitive_verb), as in *"How did you know his name?"* *"I asked him"*. Or [ditransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) - *"I asked him his name"*. If we grant that *him* and *his name* are *direct/indirect* objects there, I don't see why *what his name was* shouldn't be just another "indirect object". Nor do I see why the same shouldn't apply to *if he could swim*. (But I don't see the point of this level of terminological dissection anyway, so what do I know? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm very happy having heard StoneyB's words. For that's the way of mine, and I've suspected it might be just a Korean style. And Dowing's way is very similar with FumbleFingers. Yet, she sees NG and wh-clause all as "valencies" (as is called 'arguments in other books). So for her the two are not IO, DO, but just two arguments of the verb - ask. She also says ask is monotransitive and ditransitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional grammar would parse this sentence as:

> [<sub>Subject</sub> **I**] [<sub>Verb</sub> **asked**] [<sub>Indirect Object</sub> **him**] [<sub>Direct Object</sub> **if he could swim**]

Observe, however, that *Indirect Object* is not equivalent to *Recipient*. *Indirect Object* and *Direct Object* are **syntactical** categories: the names for different roles in the sentence. *Recipient* is a **semantic** or **thematic** category: the name for a particular role in the action described.

The distinction is important because syntactical categories may change when the sentence is “transformed”, while semantic categories remain constant. For example, if your sentence is recast into the passive voice, *HE* (with necessary inflectional changes) becomes the Subject of the sentence:

> [<sub>Subject</sub> **He**] [<sub>Verb</sub> **was asked**] [<sub>Direct Object</sub> **if he could swim**]

But the person designated by *he* is still the Recipient of the action.

It is perhaps worth noting that in an ordinary active sentence, the syntactic role of *Indirect Object* may also fill the semantic role which Functional Grammar names *Beneficiary*:

> [<sub>Subject</sub> **I**] [<sub>Verb</sub> **bought**] [<sub>Indirect Object</sub> **him**] [<sub>Direct Object</sub> **a necktie**]